# How to Use Yarn Version command to update to released version from prerelease version

Tags: git, npm, yarnpkg

I have used Yarn with git in my project to create and manage pre-release versions of my package. Now that I've completed all of my build work, I'm ready to use [the `yarn version` command](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/version/) to move beyond prerelease to official release.

I am expecting to use some form of the `yarn version` command so that my npm package version is promoted from `v0.1.1-rc.8` to `v0.1.1`; however, I see no documentation for this. I am relying on the `postversion` script within `package.json` that is invoked when I execute `yarn version` to manage the git push/tagging etc.

I'm currently using the following command line tool versions on Windows 11:

- yarn: 1.22.19
- git: 2.39.1.windows.1
- npm: 9.6.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have the answer. It appears to me that executing `yarn version --patch` (since I was operating on a pre-release for a patch) is the correct comma nd line. I am hoping to get confirmation of this. If this is correct, then the documentation seems to be lacking examples that step *all* of the way through starting a new pre-release, patch version, bumping that pre-release version, and finally completing/releasing the official new patch version - this was not clear to me.

In my actual case, sitting on the pre-release patch version `v1.0.0-rc.12`, after executing the command above, it updated to a release patch version `v1.0.0` - which is what I was wanting to do.